# How can I avoid a blue line show up when I click on a link?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a website and when I click on a link, I get this blue border around the link just during the time I am clicking it. When the new page loads, that highlighting is gone.

Here is an example screenshot how it looks right when I click on the link:

[image]

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `outline: 0;`

http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_outline.asp
http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/

Comment: The second article is (based on a quick skim) excellent and does a good job of pointing out the accessibility problems of just using the code you put in the answer. It would be nice to see some of that warning added to the answer itself. The outline property is very simple and doesn't have any security implications, so W3Schools can't go far wrong with it (as they do in many places), but their page is very light weight and best avoided.

Comment: The OP was looking for the outline property, which is pretty straight forward; I'm just giving two examples. Feel free to Google for "css outline" and use whatever resource you feel is best.